# `require': cannot load such file on running rails --help on brand new install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is getting quite frustrating. I've eventually resorted to completely removing RVM, and reinstalling from scratch, as a normal user, so restricted to my /home.

After reinstall, I've run gem update --system and gem install rails.

Then I run rails --help, and get the following error:

```
rails --help
/home/anthony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- /home/anthony/config/boot (LoadError)
    from /home/anthony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

Apparently rails thinks it should be loading a file /home/anthony/config/boot. It looks like the load path is screwed.

I've searched this out, and most people getting this error solve it with gem update --system (which I've one as above), or can at lest run rails -- or rails new . None of these work.

Final System info:

https://gist.github.com/1424644

Please help!

Comment: What's the result of `which rails` `which gem` and/or `which ruby`?

Comment: `which rails && which gem && which ruby`
`/home/anthony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@campingground/bin/rails`
`/home/anthony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/gem`
 `/home/anthony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby`

Comment: please try a `bundle exec rails`

Comment: Hmmm, that gives `Could not locate Gemfile`, so I tried "gem list" and bundler is installed (1.0.21) and so I tried just bundle and got the same message.....

Answer (score 1):

This may be totally a red herring, but it looks like your rails is in a different [gemset](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/gemsets/) - "campingground" - than either `gem` or `ruby`, which are in your default gemset. I'm not sure if this will cause the issue you're seeing or not - I believe it's OK if you're using the campingground gemset `rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p0@campingground`, but not if you're using the default gemset `rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p0` because I believe that gemsets all inherit the default gemset, but not vice versa. I've had some issues with the bin launchers of ruby helpers (like the `rails` command) barfing all sorts of confusing load errors, which are often this very issue. Again, not sure if helpful, but I'd share that shot in the dark.